# Where can I ask questions related to Windows?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What would be the right Stack Exchange community to ask questions related to Windows operating system, and Windows software? Particularly in my case, I wanted to ask questions related to oracle's virtual box.

Example of the question is as:

1. Why can't a con folder be named in windows?

Comment: 1) http://superuser.com/questions/86999/unable-to-rename-a-folder-or-a-file-as-con

Comment: If you ask a question like, "How can we run Linux after installed into a virtual box?", don't expect it to be well received.  Questions should be well researched, and that question, doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Ramhound, Sorry just a random example. So, regarding oracle's virtual box, Can we post questions on super user?

Comment: @BumbleBee Yes.

Comment: @BumbleBee - Well researched, detailed questions, that can be answered.  Your example questions are neither.

Answer (score 1):

As @Pang explained, http://superuser.com is your friend.

Windows programming questions can be asked on Stack Overflow, and professional windows system administration on Server Fault.

A Windows-specific SE site doesn't exist, but it could. Although the Windows programming questions would be probably sent to the SO also there.

Your second question is too broad.